# Finding the square root of a 7*7 matrix with real entries

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, eigenvalues

Suppose that I have the following symbolic 7*7 matrix

```
   mat= {{(a^2 b^2)/c^2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, (a^2 b^2 e11)/c^2}, {0, (a^2 b^2)/c^2,
       0, 0, 0, 0, (a^2 b^2 e22)/c^2}, {0, 0, (a^2 b^2)/c^2, 0, 0, 0, (
      a^2 b^2 e33)/c^2}, {0, 0, 0, (2 a^2 b^2)/c^2, 0, 0, (2 a^2 b^2 e12)/
      c^2}, {0, 0, 0, 0, (2 a^2 b^2)/c^2, 0, (2 a^2 b^2 e13)/c^2}, {0, 0, 
      0, 0, 0, (2 a^2 b^2)/c^2, (2 a^2 b^2 e23)/c^2}, {(a^2 b^2 e11)/
      c^2, (a^2 b^2 e22)/c^2, (a^2 b^2 e33)/c^2, (2 a^2 b^2 e12)/c^2, (
      2 a^2 b^2 e13)/c^2, (2 a^2 b^2 e23)/c^2, 
      b^2 (1 + (
         a^2 (e11^2 + 2 e12^2 + 2 e13^2 + e22^2 + 2 e23^2 + e33^2))/c^2)}}
```

for which I have the following information

a>0, b>0, c>0, {e11,e22,e33,e12,e13,e23} are Reals.

How is it possible to symbolically obtain the square root of this matrix.

What I tried so far was to Eigendecompose the matrix but it doesn't give me a closed-form solution, despite the fact that I declare the above assumptions, i.e.

```
 eigen= Assuming[{e11,e22,e33,e12,e13,e23}\[Element]Reals&&a>0&&b>0&&c>0,Eigenvalues[mat]];
```

Are there any other ways where I can find the square root of this symbolic matrix?

Comment: You can try to apply `ToRadicals` to the eigenvalues.

Comment: You could try `MatrixPower[…,1/2]`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann The first thing that I tried was MatrixPower but it wasn't useful.

Comment: @KratosMath "wasn't useful " means "doesn't evaluate"?

Comment: @UlrichNeumann It does evaluate but the final result is a mess and it includes Root, which I do not know how to treat.

Comment: @KratosMath  Result is a little bit lengthy… The root-objects can be evaluated with `Normal` if you assign values to the parameters. That means the `Root` -result can be used like other Mathematica-functions!

Comment: @UlrichNeumann It is not possible to assign all the values. I know that eij are real but I do not know their values. I would like to insert this in my FEM code.

Comment: @KratosMath Are you creating a symbolical FEM-Model? If not you have to know the parameters before inserting.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Yes I am. And in my FEM-model, a, b and c are input parameters and I know them beforehand. While eij are variables.

Answer (score 4):

Are you sure that you require *the* square root? The Cholesky factorization does often the same job and in this case, it can be computed symbolically:

```
L = Simplify[CholeskyDecomposition[mat] /. Conjugate -> Identity, {a > 0, b > 0, c > 0}]
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  \frac{a b}{c} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{a b \text{e11}}{c} \\
>  0 & \frac{a b}{c} & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{a b \text{e22}}{c} \\
>  0 & 0 & \frac{a b}{c} & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{a b \text{e33}}{c} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{2} a b}{c} & 0 & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{2} a b
>    \text{e12}}{c} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{2} a b}{c} & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{2} a b
>    \text{e13}}{c} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{\sqrt{2} a b}{c} & \frac{\sqrt{2} a b
>    \text{e23}}{c} \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & b \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

```
L\[Transpose].L - mat // Simplify
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{ccccccc}
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

Comment: Thanks for your valuable response. So as I understood from your response the Cholesky decomposition gives the square root of the matrix, is it correct always?

Comment: The Cholesky factorization of a positive (semi-)definite matrix $A$ is an upper triangular matrix $L$ such that $A = L^T L$. So it is not exactly the square root, but it shares many important properties with it. Maybe that suffices for your application? (I cannot tell because I do not know what you are about to do...)

Comment: Well, what I need is exactly the square root of the matrix. But, as you said, maybe this is enough for my case.

Comment: "what I need is exactly the square root of the matrix" I am not soo sure about it. What is it that you want to do with the square root?

Comment: The square root of the matrix is included in the FEM procedure of my code.

Comment: Yes, that is what you said before. But how _exactly_ does it enter the computations?

Comment: Well, it is a bit complicated to describe. Say I have a matrix $f$ that is 7*7 and includes the constitutive coefficients of my variables, which are seven. The conjugate of this matrix $f$ is a $g$ matrix, which is defined as $g=(f)^{-0.5}$. $g$ scales my Lagrange multipliers, i.e. $\lambda'=g \lambda$.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/106221/discussion-between-henrik-schumacher-and-kratosmath).

Answer (score 0):

There is likely not a clean expression.

Even just getting rid of a bunch of common terms and truncating to a 4 x 4 leaves you with complicated expressions, and the matrix is not sparse. Try this, to get just the first term

```
mat3 = mat[[4 ;; 7, 4 ;; 7]] /. {e11 -> 0, e22 -> 0, b -> 1, c -> 1, π -> 1}

(* {{8, 0, 0, 8 e12}, {0, 8, 0, 8 e13}, {0, 0, 8, 8 e23}, 
   {8 e12, 8 e13, 8 e23, 1 + 4 (2 e12^2 + 2 e13^2 + 2 e23^2 + e33^2)}} *)

MatrixPower[mat3, 1/2][[2, 1]]

(* complicated expression *)
```